# Resource style not found even though I already remove it and not using in Styles.xml

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2022

I created this in Styles.xml

```
<style name="Content.Right">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">60dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_round_corner_top_right</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Then, suddenly I removed this style because I will not using it anymore, but an error occur.

[image: Error message]

I already try to clean and rebuild the project, and reopen the Visual Studio but this error still occur. Also there is no file that open when I click the error.

Additionally, after remaining the style another error occur

[image]

So I added another style in Style.xml to fix the error.

[image]

Why this error occur and what is the way to fix this?

Other information:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 Version 17.1.4
- Xamarin android project
- Android 12 framework
- Windows 10

Comment: Not sure if period (.) is allowed in the style name? can you change it to something simple name?

Comment: Close VS. Delete `bin` and `obj` folders of your solution. Try again.

Comment: I think deleting `bin` and `obj` is not good solution. Sometimes it destroy my project and many error happens.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this issue.
[image]

Change:

```
<style name="Content.Right">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">60dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">20dp</item>
    ....
</style>
```

To:

```
<style name="Content_Right">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">60dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">20dp</item>
   ...
</style>
```

You could refer to Naming Practices below for xml:

- Avoid "-". If you name something "first-name", some software may think you want to subtract "name" from "first".
- Avoid ".". If you name something "first.name", some software may think that "name" is a property of the object "first".
- Avoid ":". Colons are reserved for namespaces (more later).

Comment: Do you have some link reference about this?

Comment: After changing the this `<style name="Content.Right">` to `<style name="Content_Right">` Visual studio still looking for `Content.Right`.

Comment: Have you change the name of the style which you used to `Content_Right`? If yes, clean and rebuild you project would fix this issue.

Comment: Actually, I'm not using it anymore but since the VS is finding it I put it in the style. I already rename it, clean project and solution, rebuild (Still error), close the VS and rebuild again (Still error), and clean project and solution, and rebuild again but still this error occurred.

`resource style/Content.Right not found` `failed linking reference`

Comment: Could you try to the project that you reproduce.

Comment: I just added the style you provided in `Styles.xml` and change the name to reproduce and fix.

Comment: I'm not sure why in my project its not working

Comment: Could you provide a simple example on GitHub for me to reproduce?